# Edge change Ratio

Tags: opencv, video-processing, edge-detection

I am working on Edge change Ratio Algorithm for Video shot Detection. I have the basic idea of the algorithm and have implemented a part of it using OpenCV which includes identifying edges using Canny's Algorithm.

But I am confused about how to find the edge pixels and number of entering and exiting pixels between two video frames.
I am working on OpenCV
Please help me with some code or logic or OpenCV functions to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your problem...If your gray image is `frameg` then the following API produces the image with edges..

```
Canny(frameg,frameEdge,50,150,3,false);
```

where `frameEdge` is the image containing the edges. `frameEdge` is a binary image with edge pixels being white (255) and the other pixels are black(0).

```
for(int r = 0;r<frameEdge.rows;r++)
  {
    for(int c=0;c<frameEdge.cols;c++)
     {
      if( *(frameEdge.data + frameEdge.cols*r + c) == (uchar)255 )
            {
               Point edgepixel;
               edgepixel.x = c; edgepixel.y = r;
               myedges.push_back(edgepixel);
            }
     }
  }
```

So you can easily scan the image and find the white pixels ans store their locations. That way you find the edge pixels. Make a an array `vector<Point> myedges` to store the edge pixel locations. Do this for each frame in your video and do the necessary comparisons. Note : I have taken the images as `cv::Mat`. You can use `IplImage` also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this assumes a pixel to be either completely black or white. Won't there be cases of partially colored pixels? Also I have problems with counting number of entering and exiting pixels per frames. Any help!

Comment: There wont be any partially colored pixels...after performing the Canny function on the image its just a binary image...and what exactly you mean by entering and existing pixel? can u please elaborate a little..

Comment: Suppose we have two frames E and E' to compare. So here is the definition of entering and exiting pixels I got from a research paper. "The entering edge pixel is the edge
pixels that is present in current frame E and is farther
away than r in next frame E’. The exiting edge pixel
is the edge pixel that is present in the next frame E’
and is farther away than r in current frame E." Here r can be some number of pixels say 6. Neither i got its proper meaning nor a way to do this.

Comment: got you...but to ensure that the SAME edge pixel has moved some displacement (r) you need to first ensure that a edge pixel in E is the same edge pixel in E' i.e belonging to the same edge and same position w.r.t that edge...you need to make the computer understand that two edges in two consecutive frames belong to the same feature...its like edge registration...

Comment: it would be better if you can mention what problem you want to solve by using this technique of entering-exiting edge...

Comment: Ya exactly. How to identify now that the pixel which we are considering is the same as one in previous frame at a distance of r. Actually m trying to implement Edge Change Ratio Algorithm for shot detection.

Comment: what you can do is ..detect edges in frame E and in E'..store the location of the pixels in both frames...run a neighborhood search for each edge pixel in frame E...in the neighborhood search check whether you are getting any pixels of E'or not...if positive then you assert that the same edge has moved...try to keep the neighborhood <= r pixels...dnt make it large or else you might get false detections...

Comment: Ya but how to judge that a neighborhood pixel is of the frame E'? I mean all pixels will either be black or white. So they are identical. So how will I identify that the pixel m considering is of the previous frame and and has moved a distance r. If m getting something wrong, can you please help me with some code implementation.